# Why do the negative-exponent terms vanish in this proof of the Residue theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

[This page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResidueTheorem.html) sketches a proof of the Residue theorem in which it's asserted that in:

$$
\color{grey}{
    \sum^{-\infty}_{n=-2} a_n \int_\gamma(z-z_0)^n dz
}
+ a_{-1}\int_\gamma\frac 1 {z-z_0} dz +
\color{grey}{
    \sum^\infty_{n=0} a_n \int_\gamma(z-z_0)^n dz
}
$$

The grey terms all vanish by Cauchy's integral theorem. $\gamma$ is a curve circling $z_0$. I can see why the positive (right hand) terms vanish, since $(z-z_0)^n$ is holomorphic inside $\gamma$ when $n$ is *positive*, but for negative $n$ the terms aren't holomorphic inside $\gamma$, so how can we apply Cauchy's integral theorem?

Comment: At heart, it's because there is an anti-derivative of $(z-z_0)^n$ that is holomorphic on the entire region. The anti-derivative of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ is (related to) the logarithm, and there is no way to make that holomorphic on the same region.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So for the sake of intuition, the reason the $n=-1$ case is "special" here is the same reason it's special in elementary calculus when you want to derive $x^{-n}$?

Comment: Rather, integrate $x^{-n}$, but yes.

Comment: @JackM The terms on the left vanish by Cauchy's integral formula. I suspect that is what they mean.

Comment: Either you or they may be mixing up Cauchy's integral theorem with [Cauchy's integral *formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), which gives you exactly what you need (take  $f=1$).

Comment: @NateEldredge I see it now, thanks.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't think that is the confusion involved in the above link - Cauchy's integral formula doesn't apply to $(z-z_0)^{-n}$ because (1) it is about a particular path, (2) it doesn't apply to $(z-z_0)^{-n+1}$ because that is not holomorphic in the region.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: See the second display equation on the Wikipedia page I linked, labeled "Cauchy's differentiation formula".  Of course in this case the integral can be computed directly, as in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The tricks is that you can change variables. Letting $(z-z_0)^{-1}=w$, so $z=w^{-1}+z_0$  so $dz=-w^{-2}$ you can make the same change of variable:

$$\int_{\gamma} (z-z_0)^{-n} dz = -\int_{\gamma_1} w^{n-2} dw$$ When $n=1$, $w^{n-2}$ is still not holomorphic, but when $n>1$ it is, so this value is zero.

Geometrically what is happening is that we are finding that $(z-z_0)^{-n}$ is holomorphic on a simply-connected set that includes "infinity." That's fairly advanced, but $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ is sometimes called the "Riemann sphere."